# Bash: Change String variable to the first word that starts with

Tags: string, bash

I am trying to isolate the first interface that starts with enp

Example:

```
foo = "bar0s0 foo0s8 enp0s0"
startword = "enp"
```

result:

```
$foo = enp0s0
```

Comment: errr in bash? also what have you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WORDS="bar0s0 foo0s8 enp0s0"
START="enp"

for w in $WORDS; do 
    case $w in
    ${START}*)  
             echo $w
             break # break out of the for loop for first instance
             ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: In general, it is better to use an array, `words=( bar0s0 foo0s8 enp0s0 )`.

Comment: errr while I understand what you're saying :-) I don't know where he's capturing the WORDS from.  arrays are definitely easier, yes but not if you're generating the list in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo=$(echo $foo|sed -e "s/^.*\(${startword}[^ ]*\).*$/\1/")
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using awk, modify to suit your needs:

```
 echo "bar0s0 foo0s8 enp888  enp0s0" | awk ' { for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if($i ~ "enp") { print $i; break;} } '
```

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your question as bash, so I'll provide a simple, portable solution.

Since you provide no context to your question it's hard to determine what the best approach might be but in most cases, this should do the trick.

```
bash>bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.52(2)-release (i586-suse-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
bash>foo="bar0s0 foo0s8 enp0s0 random word123"
bash>startword="enp"
bash>index=$(expr index "$foo" $startword)
bash>echo ${foo:$(($index -1)):6}
enp0s0
```

A couple of caveats:

1. This assumes you are in fact working with bash and your tools are somewhat limited.
2. This also assumes that interface names are always 6 characters.

This approach uses sub-string extraction, if you want to read up on it take a look at http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html